# Can we disable Addresses Tab in the Magento Admin Customer Grid

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer-account, admin-panel, customer-grid

In Magento Admin panel, on the customer grid section we have Customer view,Account Information, Addresses, Orders etc. In that is it possible to hide the Address Tab . Even if the customer has addresses.

Reason for hide : some of the customer has the more than 300 addresses. in that time. It is taking more time to save the customer information. Most of the time the browser get struck and browser gets killed. Mostly we will not update the Addresses through admin.

can anyone suggest how to achieve this.

Awaiting for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can

You just need to rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs` class, and just comment the addresses part

```
    $this->addTab('addresses', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Addresses'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_addresses')->initForm()->toHtml(),
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks Raul. I did it.  Address tab also hidden. But I am getting the below error "An error occurred while saving the customer." while click the save customer.

Comment: Do you think it is related to this? I mean, if you enable addresses again & save that concrete customer, the error occurs?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled and save the customer information. its working fine. I am getting this error while hiding the Address tab.  Once again thanks for your reply.

Comment: Then I cannot help you, it may be due to some concrete validation in Enterprise edition, or maybe it is caused by an extension. I cannot reproduce it

Comment: Hi Raul,  I found the solution for this issue, we need to comment the some coding in the Customercontroller.php on the SaveAction method related to address. Now its working fine.  Once again thanks for your support